# MVC implicit redirect to another JsonResult action possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, jsonresult

I have one action, and depending on the value of `foo` I want to redirect to a particular action:

```
 public JsonResult FirstAction(string foo) // foo == "SecondAction"
 {
     return RedirectToAction(foo);
 }

 public JsonResult SecondAction() { }
```

This doesn't work, since `RedirectToAction` doesn't return a `JsonResult` and there is no way of converting (as far as I'm aware).

I'm aware I could use some condition here i.e. a `switch` on `foo` in order to determine which method to invoke, but I'd like to keep it as implicit as possible.

Comment: Change the return type from `JsonResult` to `ActionResult`, from which both `JsonResult` and `RedirectResult` inherit? You're not always returning JSON from that method, so that return type you're using doesn't fit.

Comment: Huh, I guess you're creating an action for AJAX call? If so, what is the logic of "redirecting" it?

Comment: use `ActionResult` in place of `JsonResult` .. you can anyways return a JSON as the result using `return Json(yourData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` from your current action or the `SecondAction`

Comment: @Kamo - great question, it's remote validation - and how I validate depends on the value of `foo`.

Comment: In your case I'd just encapsulate this validation logic inside a method/class/service and get rid of using redirects to handle calls in your actions.

Comment: @Kamo - I think that's best. I thought `RedirectToAction` would deal with the redirect all on the server as opposed to providing the client with the redirect instruction. I thought this'd be a nice way to leverage MVC's route table in order to implicitly invoke the relevant method. Seems not.

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` responds with an Http 302, which instructs the user's browser to request a different URI.

You simply need to change the return type of your method to `ActionResult` and your code should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to execute different actions and different logic based on the value of the parameter passed to the method.

One way you could do this is using the routing system, but I would only advise you opting to this if the possible values of the parameter is of a manageable size.

Then in your **RouteConfig.cs** file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // ... other routes

    string[] possibleValueSet1 = new[] { ... };
    string[] possibleValueSet2 = new[] { ... };

    for (int i = 0; i < possibleValueSet1.Length; ++i)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "YourActionWithValueSet1_" + i.ToString(),
            url: "ControllerName/FirstAction/" + possibleValueSet1[i],
            defaults: new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "FirstAction", foo = possibleValueSet1[i] }
        );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < possibleValueSet2.Length; ++i)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "YourActionWithValueSet2_" + i.ToString(),
            url: "ControllerName/SecondAction/" + possibleValueSet2[i],
            defaults: new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "SecondAction", foo = possibleValueSet2[i] }
        );
    }

}
```

This way each possible value of foo, which should be handled by logic #1, would have an own URL, the same applies to the values which should be handled by logic #2.

I think you can already see that this goes far and whereas implicit, it is in no way more maintainable or generally better than simply implementing a decision inside the action what you pointed out you wanted to avoid. What you are asking for sounds like a "value-based overload" which C# does not allow, the code above is kind of a dirty workaround to let the routing engine do it for you, though it is not an actual overload, it is just mapping to different actions based on hardcoded possible values.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd ideally like to avoid this as specified in the OP. I'd like to be implicit in invoking the method, and using the MVC routes seems my best option rather than reflection or some verbose condition. You are right though, this is a fine approach.

Comment: Please explain your change instead of saying "how about", leaving it up to the reader to guess what you mean. Also, this question is about the return type, which you didn't change.

Comment: Well to be honest I don't see why doing an extra roundtrip (which redirect causes the client to do) is any better than implementing a simple decision logic.

Comment: I was unaware the redirect result would tell the client, but rather wanted to redirect the current request. In fact, am I not correct?

Comment: That would only be possible if the possible values of `foo` was of a manageable size, then you could use the routing system, but still, you would have to type the possible urls by hand.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your and @CodeCaster's remarks.

Comment: By manageable size I mean that there are only that many possible values that you can maintain by hand. Also, if these values are, for example, read from a database instead of being hard-coded, then the above answer should absolutely not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing RedirectToAction you should return the SecondAction itself.

```
public JsonResult FirstAction(string foo) // foo == "SecondAction"
{
     return SecondAction();
 }

 public JsonResult SecondAction() { }
```

Comment: Please be courageous to give reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the route-based approach I've described above, you should also take a look at the `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` attribute. This is an attribute on which, among others, `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` are based and lets you control whether or not the action is valid by returning a boolean value. This is the method you need to override:

```
public abstract bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo);
```

Then you could implement something like this:

```
public class ValidBasedOnFoo
{
    public int MethodNum { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var foo = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["foo"] as string;

        if (MethodNum == 1)
            return YourDecisionLogicForFirstAction(foo);
        else if (MethodNum == 2)
            return YourDecisionLogicForSecondAction(foo);
        else throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown method number.");
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, the actions are as such:

```
[ValidBasedOnFoo(1)]
public JsonResult FirstAction(string foo) { ... }

[ValidBasedOnFoo(2)]
public JsonResult SecondAction(string foo) { ... }
```

And this will allow the action to be executed if the value is proper for the action. The number used in the attribute is to tell which decision logic to use, you could just as well implement one attribute for each action if that is more clear for you.